# Sitecore 9 EXM - where is it?

Tags: exm

What happened with EXM on Sitecore 9?
The latest EXM module says it only works on SC 8.2, there isn't anything for SC 9.
I've read that it is integrated on SC now and it is not a module anymore so why can't I see it on my dashboard?
When I looked at the Marketing Automation there is no action "send email" and can't see anywhere to create the email templates.

Comment: SC 9.0 Update 1 was released and now there is a built int action to send e-mail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EXM is slated for delivery in the next update for 9.0. It was not part of the initial release.

9.0 update 1 should be available soon, but right now if you need EXM functionality today you need to use 8.2

Comment: OMG that is a major failure for Sitecore, how can you ship a CMS without e-mail support, honestly very disappointing hopefully the update 1 will be shipped soon.

Comment: As with any software, the timing at which you upgrade should be based on the features you need from the new version. The EXM module has never been a part of the core platform before nor has EXM traditonally been released at the same time that a new version of Sitecore platform has been released. There has always been a lag between release of platform and release of the EXM version compatible with that version.

As @Tamas Varga states, though, it will become a part of the platform going forward so they will release together in the future.

Answer (score 7):

There will not be a version 9 compatible EXM as it will be part of the core platform with v9 update 1.

Answer (score 5):

EXM module doesn't have yet a version compatible with Sitecore 9.

[image]

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/541788

As far I know a version compatible with Sitecore 9 will appear on next releases.